# Problem with multiple references in powerpivot. CROSSFILTER not working

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I'm trying to calculate costs of diferent work types for the employees. The Employees are part of groups. Each group has work types. Each one with it own cost.

Tables:

```
Employee    Name    Group
A           aaa     1
B           bbb     2
C           ccc     1
D           ddd     2

Date        Employee    Wtype   Duration
01/11/2022  A           X       1
02/11/2022  A           Y       2
18/11/2022  B           X       3
24/11/2022  C           X       6
30/11/2022  D           Y       3

Group   Wtype   Cost
1       X       10
1       Y       30
2       X       20
2       Y       40
```

As there are many to many relationships, i've created also the one to many tables.

```
Group
1
2

Wtype
X
Y
```

The relationships are these:

```
Active  Table 1                 Cardinality         Filter direction    Table 2
Yes     Costs [Group]           Varios a uno (*:1)  << A Costs          Groups [Group]
Yes     Costs [Wtype]           Varios a uno (*:1)  << A Costs          WTypes [Wtype]
Yes     Employees [Group]       Varios a uno (*:1)  << A Employees      Groups [Group]
Yes     Transactions [Employee] Varios a uno (*:1)  << A Transactions   Employees [Employee]
Yes     Transactions [Wtype]    Varios a uno (*:1)  << A Transactions   WTypes [Wtype]
```

I've tried to make a measure with no luck.

```
ACost:=AVERAGE(Costs[Cost])

BCost:=AVERAGEX(RELATEDTABLE(Costs);Costs[Cost])

CCost:=CALCULATE([BCost])

DCost:=CALCULATE([ACost];CROSSFILTER(Transactions[Wtype];WTypes[Wtype];Both))

ECost:=CALCULATE([ACost];
    CROSSFILTER(Costs[Wtype];WTypes[Wtype];Both);
    CROSSFILTER(Costs[Group];Groups[Group];Both);
    CROSSFILTER(Transactions[Employee];Employees[Employee];Both);
    CROSSFILTER(Transactions[Wtype];WTypes[Wtype];Both))
```

None of the above measures seems to work.

```
          ACost  BCost  CCost  DCost  ECost  Real 
A                   
 X        25     25     25     15     15     10
 Y        25     25     25     35     35     30
B                   
 X        25     25     25     15     15     20
C               
 X        25     25     25     15     15     10
D                   
 Y        25     25     25     35     35     40
```

The real cost by unit should be the one i'm writting down in the 'real' column.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ![Employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPWvH.png)
![Transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtEje.png)
![Costs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5molV.png)
![Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgBEr.png)
![Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsrVm.png)

(sorry, but my reputation doesn't allow me to post images)